# Cannot find sun.misc.URLClassPath after upgrading JAVA JDK8 to JDK11

Tags: java, runtime, java-11

I have a method to unload *.jar files at runtime using JAVA JDK 8 below. Then, I upgrade my app to use JAVA JDK 11, and it does not recognize `sun.misc.URLClassPath`.
What class in JDK 11 can be replaced it? I search on the Internet, but I have not found the answer yet.

```
import sun.misc.URLClassPath;
    
public static boolean unloadJar(String jarFile, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        try {
            if (classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
                URLClassPath ucp = (URLClassPath)getField(classLoader, "ucp", URLClassLoader.class);
                ArrayList<URL> path = (ArrayList<URL>)getField(ucp, "path");
                ArrayList<?> loaders = (ArrayList<?>)getField(ucp, "loaders");
                boolean isRemovedFromPath = path.removeIf(p -> p.getFile().endsWith(jarFile));
                boolean isRemovedFromLoaders = loaders.removeIf(l -> {
                    try {
                        URL csu = (URL)getField(l, "csu");
                        return csu.getFile().endsWith(jarFile);
                    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    
                return isRemovedFromPath && isRemovedFromLoaders;
            } else {
                String msg = String.format("Class loader type is mismatched. Required: %s, actual: %s",
                        classLoader.getClass().getName(), URLClassLoader.class.getName());
                logger.debug(msg);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `sun.` package space was/is an internal package space and should be avoided when writing production code. Since about Java 9 Oracle has been restricting access to those packages. You might be able to regain access using the features of the packaging system introduced in Java 9.

Comment: The `sun.misc.URLClassPath` class was removed in Java 9.   See https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8149122

Comment: Yes, I know the package was removed from java 9. And I am now looking for an alternative solution to keep the original business logic in the code. So, I am asking if there is a class in java 11 can be replaced for ```sun.misc.URLClassPath```

Comment: This is a horrible hack that doesn’t even do what the name claims. It doesn’t “unload” a jar, it just removes it from a list. Which achieves the opposite. After removing, not even calling the actual `close()` method on the `URLClassLoader` will clean up the resources. If you want cleanup support for dynamic class loaders, create one `URLClassLoader` for a jar (or group of jars supposed to freed together) and call `close()` on the `URLClassLoader` when done.